# How to subscribe to a file created event? (MacOS,Linux)

Tags: bash, haskell, filesystems

Is it possible to subscribe to the creation of a file with a given `Filepath`, without doing a polling every X time (MacOS,Linux) ?

1 - Do you know a haskell lib doing it ? Something like `subscribe :: FilePath -> IO ()` ?

2 - If not do you some system calls that I could use ?

Comment: What OS is this for?

Comment: MacOS and Linux distributions

Comment: Perhaps [System.FSNotify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fsnotify-0.3.0.1/docs/System-FSNotify.html)..? The **Watching** part has some functions those may come handy.